# Calculating the Odds Ratio

Tags: probability, odds-ratio

If I'm given an odds ratio table like below in a format that is not a contingency table as such,
$$\begin{array}{lll}
    \text{Duration of Doping} &    \text{Cancer Patients}   &\text{Controls} \\ 
    \text{Never}              &    235               &273\\
    <1\text{ year}              &   27               & 26\\
    1-2 \text{ years}            &  43              &  29\\
    >2 \text{ years}             & 46             &   23\\
\end{array}$$

Would I just assume that $p=\dfrac{\text{Cancer Patients}}{\text{Cancer Patients}+\text{Controls}}$ and then apply the $\dfrac{p}{1-p}$ formula? And how would I go about finding the $95\%$ confidence interval?

Comment: You want to determine 95% CI for what?

Comment: I'm trying to find 95% confidence for the odds.

Comment: You will get three ORs which one's CI do you want?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I just want to know how I can find the CI of one and whether the formula I put above is correct.

Comment: Calculate a CI for p and calculate the odds ratio at each endpoint. An "exact" CI for p will be better than the one based on the normal approximation.